# A question on the Orlicz function whose complementary function need not satisfy $\Delta_2$ condition.

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, banach-spaces, regularity-theory-of-pdes, orlicz-spaces

Is there an Orlicz function which satisfies the $\Delta_2$  condition whereas its complementary function doesn't satisfy the $\Delta_2$ condition?.

Comment: What did you try?  What are some examples failing $\Delta_2$? Do you mean $\Delta_2$ at $0$, at $\infty$ or both?

Comment: I was thinking of $e^t$. My definition of $\Delta_2$ condition for a function $\phi$ if $\exists c>0$ such that $\phi(2t)\leq c\phi(t)$ $\forall t\geq 0$.

Comment: we  probably think this as an example. $\phi(x)=(1+|x|)\log(1+|x|)-|x|$ which satisfies the $\Delta_2$ condition but it's complementary function doesn't.